# PCIe Bus error when booting Archiso and when using wifi-menu

Tags: linux, arch-linux, pci, acer

I'm trying to install Arch Linux on a Acer Spin 5 Laptop. I'm booting the latest archiso from a USB-Stick in UEFI mode and even before the system has fully started these errors appear during the boot sequence:

```
[...] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e0(Receiver ID)
[...] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: device [8086:9d16] error status/mask=00002001/00002000
[...] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: [0] Receiver Error
[...] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e0(Receiver ID)
[...] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: device [8086:9d16] error status/mask=00002001/00002000
[...] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: [0] Receiver Error      (First)
```

And lscpi tells me that `0000:00:1c.0` belongs to

```
PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
```

These errors also appear (sometimes) when using wifi-menu to connect to my wifi. Sometimes this error does not occur at all, and sometimes it's spamming my shell.

Some times the error code also is `[12] Replay Timer Timeout` and sometimes `[6] Bad TLP`, but I don't know what it depends on.

Does someone know what might cause this error and how to fix it?
It's very annoying and hindering me from installing arch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

1. `cp /etc/default/grub ~/Desktop`
2. Edit grub. Add `pci=noaer` or `pci=nommconf` at the end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Line will be like this:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
   ```
3. `sudo cp ~/Desktop/grub /etc/default/`
4. `sudo update-grub`
5. Reboot now